# Finding the velocity vector

Tags: parametric

Am I finding the equation of the slope of the tangent line at c(t)?

$\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$ = $\frac{2t}{3t^2-8}$

[image]

Comment: Isn't the velocity=$\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2+(\dfrac{dx}{dt})^2} $, using Pythagoras Theorem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the particle at any particular time will be given by the vector

```
r(t) = (x(t),y(t))
```

You want to differentiate r(t), i.e,

```
 v(t) = dr(t)/dt = (dx(t)/dt,dy(t)/dt)
```

Note that the speed will be given by

```
 s(t) = d/dt of sqrt(x(t)^2+y(t)^2), but that is not the velocity or a vector
```

Comment: To make it a vector, we need the direction. $\arctan \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$ is the direction angle w.r.t the horizontal.